# Spotify OAuth in WFP C# app - cannot complete authentication process

Tags: wpf, async-await, oauth, callback, spotify

I'm trying to extend an existing WPF app that I use to search Spotify so that I can add new playlists in my account based on a whole bunch of M3U playlist files that I have from a music app I no longer use.  (I know there are free tools to do this but they are mostly useless so I want to roll my own as I have extra matching logic I want to apply).

So I'm using SpotifyAPI-Net from Github with PKCE authorisation and have implemented what I think should work according to this page: https://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/docs/pkce.

At present my code is doing the following:

1. Start an HttpListener to listen on http://localhost:5543/callback/ when my window loads. (This URL has been specified in the Spotify dashboard as required for the callbacks to work.)

   ```
    private const string CallbackURL = "http://localhost:5543/callback/";  

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //If we do a plain Await here it blocks the UI from running
        Task.Run(() => StartServer());
    }

        public async Task StartServer()
        {
            //Set up listener for callback on http://localhost:5543/callback/
            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add(CallbackURL );  
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                var context = listener.GetContext();
                if (context != null)
                {
                    authCode = context.Request.QueryString["code"];
                    await GetCallback(authCode);
                    break;
                }
            }
            listener.Stop();
        }
   ```
2. I'm then generating the Spotify loginURL with the auth request as follows:

   ```
    public void BuildSpotifyAuthURL()
    {
        // Generates a secure random verifier of length 100 and its challenge
        var (verifier, challenge) = PKCEUtil.GenerateCodes();

        var loginRequest = new LoginRequest(
          new Uri(CallbackURL),
          SPOTIFYUTIL_CLIENT_ID,
          LoginRequest.ResponseType.Code
        )
        {
            CodeChallengeMethod = "S256",
            CodeChallenge = challenge,
            Scope = new[] { Scopes.PlaylistReadPrivate, Scopes.PlaylistReadCollaborative }
        };
        LoginUri = loginRequest.ToUri();

        Process.Start(LoginUri.ToString());
    }
   ```

This gives me a URL like this:
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a5543%2fcallback%2f&scope=playlist-read-private+playlist-read-collaborative&code_challenge=Fc-GVHr1dzlLMPwuQw0e4Ex3c1w8xv5c5rNym-N6tPU&code_challenge_method=S256

Since this is a WPF app I run Process.Start() to open the URL in my default browser (Firefox). It then shows me the page asking me to agree to the usage terms so I click 'Agree' and the listener fires as expected and I see a URL like "http://localhost:5543/callback/?code=" (also as expected) but when the GetCallback method below fires it never gets past the "await new OAuthClient(...)" line - i.e: it does not get to to the next line where I try to create the SpotifyClient.

```
    public async Task GetCallback(string code)
    {
        var (verifier, challenge) = PKCEUtil.GenerateCodes();
        var initialResponse = await new OAuthClient().RequestToken(
                new PKCETokenRequest(SPOTIFYUTIL_CLIENT_ID, code, new System.Uri(CallbackURL), verifier)  
        );
   
        //Code never gets here but this is the same as the example code on the GitLab website... guessing await above is returning the Task immediately
        spotifyClient = new SpotifyClient(initialResponse.AccessToken);
        var user = spotifyClient.UserProfile.Current();
        txtPLTestOutput.Text = user.Result.DisplayName;
    }
```

So from debugging I can see as soon as it's got the instance of Task it is returning but the problem is that even if I make 'initialResponse' a global variable it never gets a value, so even if I try to do the last three lines somewhere else (like in another Button event handler or method) it shows as null.

I think this is an aysnc issue more than an OAuth issue but I'm not sure how I'm meant to store the instance of PKCETokenResponse so it can be used to create the instance of SpotifyClient.

I've not done much C# in the last few years so if anyone can point out where I might be going wrong I'd really appreciate it, I've tried for hours and hours to fix it with no luck.